P-value vs confidence interval interpretation
Refreshing on hypothesis testing. A p-value is defined as "the probability that an observation would be as or more extreme than observed given that the null hypothesis is true." The null hypothesis generally is zero; for example, zero difference between means, coefficient of zero in regressions, etc.
This value says nothing of the alternative hypothesis; for example, the difference between means is not zero. $P(X \ge observation|N_0=True)$
Which leads me to wonder, what about confidence intervals? In other words, do they assume that $N_0=True$ ? Or do they make a statement about $P(X)$, instead? Because the confidence interval might not include zero (statistical significance!)
My understanding of the CI is that the 95% (or x%) interval around the mean is the best guess given the sample and corresponding random error. But this might not be the same as $P(X)$; this is just an intuition and I can't explain why.

Could you please clarify what you mean by "$X$" and by "$observation$" and how those two differ? // Concerning your question, have you read our thread about what confidence intervals are?


"A p-value is defined as "the probability that an observation would be as or more extreme than observed given that the null hypothesis is true." This is absolutely correct.
"This value says nothing of the alternative hypothesis". This is not correct. The alternative is valid iff it is the exact logical opposite of the null ($H_a=¬H_0$). If you reject the null, the only statement you can accept is the exact opposite of the null. In this case, $p=P(data|H_0)=1-P(data|H_a)$. So if the data is very unlikely under $H_0$, then the data is very likely under $H_a$. This is why, if we reject the null, we can/should accept the alternative.
CI's do not assume the null is true. They are based on other assumptions (parametric or not). But they are the flip side of the same coin as the NHST. If the p-value is $<\alpha$, then the $100*(1-\alpha)$% CI will not contain 0, and vice-versa. (0 or whatever your hypothesized value is: let's use 0 for simplicity).
We really would like to know $P(H_0|Data)$, and in fact what we really want is $P(H_a|Data)$ (which is  $1-P(H_0|Data)$, iff ($H_a=¬H_0$))
All of these are conditional probabilities, so indeed we can apply Bayes' theorem to them. So let's do it:
$P(H_a|Data)=\frac{P(Data|H_a).P(H_a)}{P(Data)}$        (1)

Now $P(Data)$ can be decomposed as $P(Data|H_a).P(H_a)+P(Data|H_0).P(H_0)$. We also have $P(Data|H_a)=(1-p)$, and $P(Data|H_0)=p$
We get $P(H_a|Data)=\frac{(1-p).p(H_a)}{(1-p).P(H_a)+p(1-P(H_a))}$ (2)
Or $P(H_a|Data)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{p.(1-P(H_a))}{(1-p).P(H_a)}}$  (3)
So we now have this $P(H_a)$ term. What is it? This is basically the prior probability of your alternative hypothesis (yes, it sounds Baeysian, as expected, because we applied his theorem). What does that mean? That means how likely is it for $H_a$ to be true? This will make some purist frequentists cringe; but as we do not know if $H_a$ is true, there is uncertainty, and if there is uncertainty, we can assign it a probability. You can also understand it as the prevalence of real effects (Colquhoun's interpretation). Or you can understand it as the probability of your study being sufficiently powered to detect an effect. These last 2 are equivalent, and should be more palatable to "pure" frequentists.
For example, assuming p=.05 (tradition...), using equation (2), we get:

If $P(H_a)$=.9, $P(H_a|Data)=.994$
If $P(H_a)$=.5, $P(H_a|Data)=.95$
If $P(H_a)$=.05, $P(H_a|Data)=.5$
If $P(H_a)$=.01, $P(H_a|Data)=.161$

Note that in the special case where $P(H_a)=.5$, we have $P(H_a|Data)=P(Data|H_a)=1-p$
As we can see, for the same p-value, I get different answers to the question I really wanted to know (how likely is $H_a$, given the data)... Vexing...
So why do we compute p-values, which are $P(data|H_0)$? Because we can, w/o any estimate of the prior of $P(H_0)$ or $P(H_a)$. In most real life cases, we have no clue about $P(H_a)$, and note that, if we assume 50%/50% for $H_a/H_0$, then the p-value gives us exactly what we wanted...
Should one then use Bayesian statistics? Now you enter the debate of properly chosing the priors? There the choice is between objectively computing what we do not really want to know $(P(Data|H_0))$, or computing what we really want to know $(P(H_a|Data))$, but subjectively. Tough one...
And can we compute something else? If we could, we would have...
Do not however conclude that p-values is a "bad" tool. It is not; it works exactly as advertised. Would you blame mammograms for producing a huge amount of false positives when used on the entire female population? (as opposed to "at risk" women). No, you would blame the doctors for not understanding the prevalence of the condition. Note that this same "prevalence" ($P(H_a)$) also explains, in great part, why "Most Published Research Studies are False" wiki. Because NHST controls for $\alpha$ errors, but not for FDR (False Discovery Rate) (which depends on $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $P(H_a)$). But that is for another answer...

Thank you for the detailed response, it cleared some things up for me! Where I’ve gone awry in the past, is interpreting the CI as akin to a posterior $P(H_a|Data)$. $H_a$ is simply the claim that $H_0$ is false, but this shouldn’t bolster our confidence in the MLE fit represented by the CI.

Related, suppose a T-test where the t-value is found to be 3; in other words the observed difference of means was found to be 3 standard deviations away from 0. From the parametric CI perspective, there exists some mean and standard deviation. The value 0 (no difference between means) should be 3 CI’s standard deviations from the CI’s computed mean. Is this conclusion fair?

Let me rephrase your example. Suppose a 1-sample t-test, with 20 samples: the 95% CI will have a width of +/-0.468 around the observed mean. A 2-tailed t-test will see how far away your hypothesized null (not necessarily 0) is from the observed mean: if it is exactly 0.468 away, your p-value will be .05. You can think of the CI allocating $\alpha$ errors around the observed statistic; but $\alpha$ errors occur only when the null is true... So CI's and p-values will never disagree. Note that some tests do not give actionable CI's (e.g. F test for ANOVA: it is computable, but not informative)

I find this completely confusing at the point it departs from hypothesis testing and introduces extraneous ideas from Bayesian analysis at step 4: in the NHST  framework, you cannot apply Bayes' Theorem, because there is no assumption that the distribution parameters are random variables.
